# Отсутствуют необходимые пакеты для gRPC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, nuget, grpc

Создал gRPC службу в VS2019 и в стандартной реализации отсутствуют необходимые юзинги: Microsoft.AspNetCore, Microsoft.Extensions, Grsp.Core и их производные. Подчеркивает красным и пишет что отсутствуют директивы. Для VS установил ASP.NET и разработка веб-приложений. Попытка автоматически добавить нужные элементы через nuget выдала ошибку установки и в целом nuget перестал работать. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать? Поможет ли просто переустановка VS?

Comment: .NET 6 надо использовать и ASP.NET Core 6, а не ASP.NET, который работает на базе устаревшего .NET Framework 4.x

Comment: VS 2022 лучше используйте, во избежание всяких проблем с обратной совместимостью. Тем более если хотите работать с gRPC